# Issue adding children to grid system

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, for-loop, grid

I am fairly new to AS3. I have been wracking my brain trying to figure this out. I have a grid system laid out. Each grid block is instanced row1, row2, etc.

I have some code repeatedly adding children using for (var i:int = 0; i < 81; i++).

Within that for block in the end, it adds row.addChild(item); Isn't there a way to make the row + i so it will automatically name that row and add the child into it? Both books I have don't even mention it, although they use some sort of [i] or (i) for some other stuff.

Any help would be truly appreciated, as I have been stuck on this problem for days now, and my internet searches are just not working for this issue.

Here is my code:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 81; i++) {
        var item:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        //item.fnumber = i;
        item.ftype = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 1); 


                        if (item.ftype == 1) {
                        var item:MovieClip = new item(); item.fnumber = i; item.fcolor = ""; item.ftype = 1}
                        if (item.ftype == 2) {
                        var item:MovieClip = new item2(); item.fnumber = i; item.fcolor = ""; item.ftype = 2}
                        if (item.ftype == 3) {
                        var item:MovieClip = new item3(); item.fnumber = i; item.fcolor = ""; item.ftype = 3}
                        if (item.ftype == 4) {
                        var item:MovieClip = new item4(); item.fnumber = i; item.fcolor = ""; item.ftype = 4}
                        if (item.ftype == 5) {
                        var item:MovieClip = new item5(); item.fnumber = i; item.fcolor = ""; item.ftype = 5}
                        if (item.ftype == 6) {
                        var item:MovieClip = new item6(); item.fnumber = i; item.fcolor = ""; item.ftype = 6}



                    row.addChild(item);
                    item.flevel = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows:Array = [];
var mcs:Array = [item, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];

for(var n:int = 0; n<10; n++) {
    var row:Sprite = new Sprite();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 81; i++) {

        var ftype = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 1); 
        var item:MovieClip = new mcs[ftype]();
        item.fnumber = i;
        item.fcolor = "";
        item.ftype = ftype;
        item.flevel = 1;

        row.addChild(item);

    }
    addChild(row);
    rows.push(row);
 }
```

Now you can access rows with `rows[i]`.

Comment: Et, si les rows sont des elements déjà existants et présent sur ta timeline, tu peux simplement utiliser le même système de remplissage de mcs, et retirer la création des rows: var rows:Array = [row1, row2, row3 ...]

Comment: I thank you for your response, but it's just not working. I don't think I can do what I am trying to do. Each row isn't really a row, but a single block already on the screen. They are named row1, row2, etc. I am trying to add items into each block by using a for loop to do it. I thought I'd be able to use an array and then add the item child into each block, but that isn't working. 

I wanted something like row[i].addChild(item), but that is obviously wrong. Thank you anyway Baris!

Comment: I come from programming in PHP. I wish there was an echo command LOL!

Comment: In a nutshell, what I'm trying to achieve is rows.push("row" + i); 
      var row = rows[i]; 
      row.addChild(item);

Answer (score 0):

If you are to address a component which name is computed, use `this[computedName]` approach. Make sure, however, that you won't end up with null or undefined querying this, which can happen if you mis-name your components. Altering code of Baris:

```
var rows:Array = [];
var mcs:Array = [item, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];

for(var n:int = 1; n<10; n++) {
    var row:MovieClip=this["row"+n]; // <-- this is the trick
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 81; i++) {

        var ftype = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 1); 
        var item:MovieClip = new mcs[ftype]();
        item.fnumber = i;
        item.fcolor = "";
        item.ftype = ftype;
        item.flevel = 1;

        row.addChild(item);

    }
    // addChild(row); this is not needed, as you have your rows already on screen
    rows.push(row);
 }
```

Baris had there a couple of tricks for you to learn and master too, like creating an array of classes to randomly select from.